# Attaching js to a html button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to attach this script to a HTML button but can't seem to get my head around it.

Javascript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
        if (getElementById(button));    
        var sumOfNumbers = 0;
        var numberOfLoops = 20;
        var counter = 1;
        while (counter <= numberOfLoops){
            alert(sumOfNumbers);
            sumOfNumbers += counter;
            counter++;
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><input type="button" id="button" value="Loop"/></p>
```

Comment: What's up with the return on the first line?

Comment: You're returning on the first line ?

Comment: What do you mean by attach the script to the button? Are you talking about using it with a click event or something like that?

Comment: Are you looking to modify the HTML so that it calls the JavaScript, or add additional JavaScript that will attach the function to the button at run time?

Comment: The more you look at that code, the more it hurts !

Comment: Yes im trying to make it a click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add an event listener to the button?

See <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KA6k6/1/)</kbd>

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

if (button.addEventListener){
    button.addEventListener('click', function() { $(); });    
} else if (button.attachEvent){ // IE < 9 :(
    button.attachEvent('onclick', function() { $(); });
}

var $ = function() {
        var sumOfNumbers = 0;
        var numberOfLoops = 20;
        var counter = 1;
        while (counter <= numberOfLoops){
            alert(sumOfNumbers);
            sumOfNumbers += counter;
            counter++;
        }
}
```

Also, if you have Firebug or Chrome developer console, swap the `alert()` call with a `console.log()` call. Alerts can get annoying, especially if they are displayed back-to-back; consecutively.

**Local File Example:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ready = function() {
            var button = document.getElementById('button');

            if (button.addEventListener){
                button.addEventListener('click', function() { $(); });    
            } else if (button.attachEvent){ // IE < 9 :(
                button.attachEvent('onclick', function() { $(); });
            }

            var $ = function() {
                var sumOfNumbers = 0;
                var numberOfLoops = 20;
                var counter = 1;
                while (counter <= numberOfLoops){
                    alert(sumOfNumbers);
                    sumOfNumbers += counter;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="ready()">
        <p><input type="button" id="button" value="Loop" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works in jsfiddle, but not in aptana for me.

Comment: Place the code in the `document.onLoad` function. Looks like the button is not ready during: `var button = document.getElementById('button');`

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, <body onLoad="ready()"> seemed to fix it.

Comment: Whenever you try to get document elements in the head of an HTML document you need to make sure that everything has been created.